# Container command '/start.sh' not found or does not exist, entrypoint to container is shell script

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Project contents:

```
rob@work:~/git/proj $ ls
lib     node_modules  props.json    start.sh
app.js  Dockerfile    package.json  README.md
```

`start.sh` ..

```
rob@work:~/git/proj $ cat start.sh 
#/bin/bash

# do things
/some/other/stuff

echo "Starting app .."
node app.js
```

`Dockerfile` ..

```
FROM somewhere.com/dependencyProj
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
COPY props.json /etc/someService.d/props.json
EXPOSE 4101

ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

Build docker image:

```
rob@work:~/git/proj $ docker build -t dx/proj:0.0.1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 59.99 MB
Step 1 : FROM somewhere.com/dependencyProj
latest: Pulling from dependencyProj
420890c9e918: Already exists 
8ff1af46fe3d: Already exists 
6db3a1c6f4ca: Already exists 
d82a90c4ea1b: Already exists 
f32685681727: Already exists 
797dfb291196: Already exists 
3a713b0b523e: Already exists 
a9c617bff63b: Already exists 
9ab84732ac6e: Already exists 
2a85e0afdd4d: Already exists 
a56b24146ce4: Already exists 
0a91b00da1f7: Already exists 
836b0e7c1105: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:36b7a32bd12b85cbb2fb3203d43807c9b8735d6ceb50d813b76bfe2e5c3ebeb4
Status: Downloaded newer image for somewhere.com/dependencyProj:latest
 ---> 7c52bbbc3feb
Step 2 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in aab7cf1f7974
 ---> 250317f63adf
Removing intermediate container aab7cf1f7974
Step 3 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in f60088532610
 ---> 60f3d9fe88c4
Removing intermediate container f60088532610
Step 4 : COPY . /usr/src/app
 ---> 004e0a440fb5
Removing intermediate container f247d134d88b
Step 5 : COPY props.json /etc/someService.d/props.json
 ---> 03b48249c94c
Removing intermediate container a3636849765d
Step 6 : EXPOSE 4101
 ---> Running in 0056e5c20264
 ---> 867765176927
Removing intermediate container 0056e5c20264
Step 7 : ENTRYPOINT /start.sh
 ---> Running in 80ae316b0629
 ---> d1e65def77ce
Removing intermediate container 80ae316b0629
Successfully built d1e65def77ce
```

Run docker image:

```
rob@work:~/git/proj $ docker run -d dx/proj:0.0.1
0fd1f8087cc5be3e085454cf99b7a3795b9ce15909b0f416ae39380f93feaa44
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '/start.sh' not found or does not exist..
```

Comment: It's `./start.sh`.

Comment: I get `docker: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec format error".` if using `./start.sh`

Comment: Did you add executable permission for `start.sh`? Try `chmod +x start.sh`.

Comment: same error if I put `RUN chmod +x start.sh` before `ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]`

Comment: Your shebang is wrong, it's `#!/bin/bash`, not `#/bin/bash`.

Comment: typos! those 2 changes resolved issue if you want to add answer ill accept it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have some issues:

- You must use `./start.sh` to run the `start.sh` file from current directory. `/start.sh` run `start.sh` in root `/`, which does not exist.
- Your shebang line in `start.sh` script is wrong, it's must be `#!/bin/bash`.
- You also must set executable permission for `start.sh`, by running `chmod +x start.sh`.

Comment: I had to change the line endings in the bash script from CRLF to LF.
With CRLF line endings, i got the same error.

Comment: spent a few hours stuck on this and this is what happened to me, when my intellij committed the file it converted the file endings!

Comment: @Gnagy: that's worth an answer. It was also the case on my device.

Comment: @Gnagy THANK YOU, that did it for me.  It's always the little things huh.

Comment: @Gnagy WOW! That was it as well!

Comment: For me the error was triggered by running in an alpine without bash. Strangely didn't complain that cannot find `/bin/bash`. I changed the shebang to `#!/bin/sh` and was ok.

Answer (score 120):

On windows, while building the docker image, i also used to get the same error after building the image, that shell script is missing.. the path and the shebang was  also correct.

Later on, i read some where that it may be due to the encoding issue. I just opened the file in sublime editor and then..VIEW->Line Endings-> UNIX and just save the file, and rebuilded the image. Everything worked fine.

I was getting this error, when i was building a image from windows.

Other Option:

Sometime, we forgot to manually change the line format. So,what we can do is add this **Run** statement before the EntryPoint in **dockerfile**. It will encode the file in LF format.

```
 RUN sed -i 's/\r$//' $app/filename.sh  && \  
        chmod +x $app/filename.sh

ENTRYPOINT $app/filename.sh
```

Comment: It actually worked, thanks! For others, mind you that the *script file* itself has to use LF-style line endings (meaning that the lines should use \n as line endings instead of \r\n).

Comment: Omg... lost so many times because of that... I cloned a git repository and forgot that Git for Windows converts LF to CRLF (and does the opposite when you push).

Comment: This was the correct answer for me (running Docker for Windows) where I'd used VS Code to modify a '.sh' file forgetting it'll save it with CR-LF line endings. For someone who doesn't have Sublime Text, you can use Notepad++ to change these back to Linux line-endings.

Comment: Thank you! This was also my issue. VSCode makes it really easy to change line endings thankfully but it had me confused for a while. Weird error message. It exists, I'd assume I'd get some `filename.sh: corrupted` error message or something. Instead error message was `does not exist` which threw me off

Comment: Mine issue was also same. Everytime In my dockerfile when i am copying a linux system file like crontab or any script there were some characters ^m were added at the end of each line. I can think to add a command dos2unix in dockerfile after running the copy command. Is there any other reliable soultion that i can use ?

Comment: This solved my problem. It started suddenly not working, I have spent hours on this. Caused by using a wrong editor once, saving it in windows style. Thx.

Comment: Despite having my script file locally with LF-style line endings, a setting in our Git repo converted the file to CRLF on the build server, causing the script to fail in the Docker container. +1 for including the `sed` fix, which I will now use.

Comment: The bottom line is that we should probably get Linux or Mac

Comment: Oh my god, thank you for pointing this out. This encoding thing makes me crazy when building docker images. In Windows and VSCode, it worked fine when I change from the encoding from CRLF to LF.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, `#!/bin/bash` didn't work. I needed to use `#!/bin/sh`

Answer (score 1):

Common issue on Windows - just change line endings.

1. Open terminal eq. `git bash`
2. Run `dos2unix ./*` to convert line endings
3. Rebuild and restart docker image