# Docker run won't find shell script

Tags: docker, sh

I've created a docker image, and attempted to run it like this:

```
IMAGE=$(docker build --network=host -q .)

docker run \
        --network=host \
        --rm $IMAGE sh -c "cd bamboo && ./publish.sh"
```

The output is:

```
sh: ./publish.sh: not found
```

This variation of the command

```
IMAGE=$(docker build --network=host -q .)

docker run \
        --network=host \
        --rm $IMAGE sh -c "cd bamboo && ls -l"
```

shows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 node     node           646 Nov 25 01:40 publish.sh
```

Outside the container (whose content is copied into the container via the docker file), while in same parent folder as the above script, running

```
cd bamboo & ./publish.sh
```

works as expected.  Any ideas what I can be doing wrong?

I found this similar question:
[Container command '/start.sh' not found or does not exist, entrypoint to container is shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419042/container-command-start-sh-not-found-or-does-not-exist-entrypoint-to-contain)

and it mentioned line ending on Windows (where I am running Docker) can be problematic.  I confirmed my line ending are LF rather than CRLF.

EDIT: The first few lines of the called script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

SCRIPTDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
```

and my dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:12.16.2-alpine3.11

WORKDIR /app

# node image creates node user for security purposes
RUN chown -R node:node /app

USER node

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN yarn install --no-progress --pure-lockfile

RUN yarn build
```

Comment: What's the first line of the script?  (Or, if it's really only 646 bytes, what's the entire script?)  What's in the Dockerfile?  In particular this can happen if you declare a script to require a non-standard shell (like `#!/bin/bash`) but use a base image that doesn't have it (like Alpine).

Comment: Thanks David, I updated the question.  And you're 100% right - my base image is alpine.  Sorry for my ignorance, but is bash a non-stand shell? What could I use with alpine?

Comment: The Alpine base image in particular contains a very light-weight shell implementation that confirms to the POSIX standard, but no more; the `$BASH_SOURCE` environment variable and array-variable syntax aren't part of the standard.  You can use `#!/bin/sh` instead, if you limit yourself to the standard shell features.

Comment: Excellent, thank you David